# how to check cpu utilization of pods in aws using prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, cpu-usage

I need to check the CPU utilization in percentage for an individual pods which has been integrated with the Prometheus.
I was checking it with using **container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"ordermgmtquery"}**
And also i tried with **rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!~"POD|"}[50m])**
These also kinda didn't help me much.

Let me know if there is any other query which could help me fetch the exact CPU utilization with percentage.

I tried with  **container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"ordermgmtquery"}**
And also i tried with **rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!~"POD|"}[50m])**
These also kinda didn't help me much.

But i'm getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8V2w.png)

But i'm looking for a graph which could depicts the CPU utilization in percentage instead of milliunits